# Docker - Starting CRON as non-root user

Tags: docker, cron

I'm currently having issues with cron in my docker container.  After building the container and installing cron, I set the entrypoint as:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "cron && sleep 99d"]
```

I have a shell file in `/etc/cron.hourly/` that is valid (tested using run-parts).

However, I am also running my container as a non-root user.  So when I shell into my container after starting it, cron is not running, and I cannot start the service.  Before switching to this non-root user, I am also trying to directly run the command

```
RUN cron

USER non-root
```

But this also does not seem to start the process.  The issue being that the cron.pid file requires root access to write to.  Obviously if I start the container as a root user, the cron process starts.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?  The only thing missing currently is the cron service not starting on container startup.

Comment: A container is a wrapper around a single _process_; it doesn't "run services" _per se_.  Do you need to run `cron -n` as a foreground process in its own container?  Since the cron daemon can run processes as any user it does intrinsically need to run as root.

Comment: @DavidMaze Basically this container is running as a sidecar to another container to run backups, and I would like cron to execute these backup scripts in the cron.hourly folder.  Once the container starts, I am not doing any modifications to it, so I just want cron to run, everything is already in place (but for security purposes we run as non-root).  My only problem is when the container starts, cron is not running, and I can't seem to start it in my Dockerfile

Comment: And if I don't switch to a non-root user, I can include `cron start` in the entry point and it works.  If I switch to a non root beforehand, cron is not started

Comment: If I was setting that up, I might set up the data that needs to be persisted in a bind-mounted host directory, and then use the host's cron daemon to run the backup.  You could in principle also do it with a dedicated cron container and a shared named volume.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option I found is to change the `root` user password:

```
# cron
RUN echo 'root:toor' | chpasswd
COPY crontab /crontab
RUN crontab /crontab
CMD echo 'toor' | su -c cron && php -a
# /cron

USER non-root
```